# How to place my email validation script into a php function

Tags: php, function, validation

Struggling to create a function to validate any email address using the script below

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=^.{6,64}$)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._\-&!?=#]*@/', $user_mail)) {
            $error_mail        = empty_mail;
            $display_form      = TRUE;
            $validation_error  = TRUE;
          } else {
            $domain = preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._\-&!?=#]*@/', '', $user_mail);
            if (!checkdnsrr($domain)) {
              $error_mail        = empty_mail;
              $display_form      = TRUE;
              $validation_error  = TRUE;
            }
          }
```

Comment: [What is a function in PhP ?](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: Or just [`filter_var($user_mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`](http://php.net/filter-var)?

Comment: Why do you want to validate an email when it is sent to the server? I would rather suggest you validate it using javascript or jquery in the front end itself. It would reduce overhead on the server and would save you an extra step.

Comment: function validateEmail() {

place validation code in here

}

Answer (score 0):

**Server-side validation:**

It is a good idea to always validate data server-side.
Of course you need to do this client site with JavaScript but you can never trust client validation because you can easily pass that.

**That said, hereby the simple PHP server-side e-mail address validation:**

```
//Will return a boolean
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

**Documentation:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 0):

Define the function and call the function with parameters like this

```
    <?php

    function validate_email($user_mail)
    {

       $pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/";

       if (preg_match($pattern, $user_mail)) {

          return "valid email format";
       }
       else
       {
          return "Invalid email format";
       }


    }

    echo validate_email('jothi007@@gmail.com');

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
valid email format
```